# How to display runs with different stages on multibranch pipeline status page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

Jenkins will only display the stages since the last change to the list of the stages in the job. So for example if in the Jenkinsfile you removed one stage and it went down from 4 to 3 total stages then all previous runs stages will not be displayed on the main page for multibranch pipeline's branch job. Only the latest one will be and the newer ones that have 3 stages. If you add back that removed stage then again - only the newest run with those 4 stages will appear and all runs with 3 stages will disappear.

How to show all runs?